# How to get a 1px border between columns?

Tags: susy-compass

What is the preferred / cleanest method to draw a 1px border between two Susy grid items, in the center of the gutter?

Susy creates a gutter by adding a margin-right to a grid item, so I can't simply add a border-right (like, for instance, you *can* do with [Zen Grids](http://zengrids.com/), which creates gutters by applying half a gutter-width of padding on both sides).

I guess it can be done using the `with-grid-settings()` mixin to define an alternative grid without gutters, but that feels like a messy solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a great solution at the moment, but I hope to have one in the next major release. What you can do, is create your own math using the Susy functions (really the most powerful part of Susy). Something like this:

```
.left-column {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
  float: left;
  width: columns(2) + gutter()/2;
  padding-right: gutter()/2;
  margin-right: gutter()/2;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. Even though this is not the dead-simple idiot-proof solution I was hoping for, it's good to read that it's being considered. Does it help if I open a formal feature request on github?

Comment: Formal requests always help. :) The problem is: once we start adding dead-simple solutions for every single edge case, we would very quickly become a bloated behemoth of rarely-used mixins. I think functions that allow you to solve your own edge cases are a much better and more flexible api. Learn the functions, and you can make anything happen. Count on the mixins, and you're dependent on us to solve every single edge-case for you.

Comment: OK, Point taken. Dead-simple should not be the only goal.

Comment: @EricMeyer is the solution in the next major release include border-box-sizing? Using it, I was able to add borders without breaking the layout, but they're not centered. I can create a new question if you think it would help future searchers.

Comment: Yes, border-box-sizing solves half the problem. In Susy 2.0 (currently near the end of alpha development) you can also apply your gutters in various ways: before, after, split, or inside (split padding). That simplifies the solution above down to: .left-column { @include span(2 inside); border-right: 1px solid; }. I hope that meets the "dead-simple" requirements above. :)

Comment: @EricMeyer span didn't work. I assume you meant span-columns. It doesn't appear to make any difference. I setting up a three column layout with .left-col { include span-columns(4 inside, 12); border-right: 1px solid $darkRed;} {I had to drop the at sign to make Stack Overflow happy]
I actually need to put both borders on my center column so that they will be equal. How long for 2.0 to be released? Is it going to be weeks or months? I currently have a three column mixin that I wrote that works so I can wait. I'd prefer yours so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @curt span is part of Susy 2.0. span-columns does not have that same functionality. You would have to download the alpha to use it. I hope to be out of alpha soon, but it's hard to make any promises on open-source work.